# Why do I get a build error when trying to build Veins VLC on OMNeT++?

Tags: omnet++, veins

I'm trying to build veins-vlc module on Omnet++ but I keep getting the following error.

```
make MODE=debug all 
make[1]: Entering directory '/c/Users/uthpa/Documents/OMNET++/omnetpp-5.7/workspace/veins_vlc-master/src'
Creating shared library: ../out/gcc-debug/src/libveins-vlc_dbg.dll
lld-link: error: duplicate symbol: veins::Coord::info[abi:cxx11]() const
>>> defined at ../../veins-veins-5.2/src/veins/base/utils/Coord.h:338
>>>            ../out/gcc-debug/src/veins-vlc/PhyLayerVlc.o
>>> defined at libveins_dbg.dll

lld-link: error: duplicate symbol: non-virtual thunk to veins::BaseModule::finish(omnetpp::cComponent*, int)
>>> defined at ../../veins-veins-5.2/src/veins/base/modules/BaseModule.h:111
>>>            ../out/gcc-debug/src/veins-vlc/PhyLayerVlc.o
>>> defined at libveins_dbg.dll

lld-link: error: duplicate symbol: non-virtual thunk to veins::BatteryAccess::~BatteryAccess()
>>> defined at ../../veins-veins-5.2/src/veins/base/modules/BatteryAccess.h:49
>>>            ../out/gcc-debug/src/veins-vlc/PhyLayerVlc.o
>>> defined at libveins_dbg.dll

lld-link: error: duplicate symbol: non-virtual thunk to veins::BatteryAccess::~BatteryAccess()
>>> defined at ../../veins-veins-5.2/src/veins/base/modules/BatteryAccess.h:49
>>>            ../out/gcc-debug/src/veins-vlc/PhyLayerVlc.o
>>> defined at libveins_dbg.dll
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [Makefile:127: ../out/gcc-debug/src/libveins-vlc_dbg.dll] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/c/Users/uthpa/Documents/OMNET++/omnetpp-5.7/workspace/veins_vlc-master/src'
make: *** [Makefile:36: all] Error 2
"make MODE=debug all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.

21:03:48 Build Failed. 2 errors, 0 warnings. (took 996ms)
```

I have already imported veins and built it without issues.
I use omnetpp 5.7, veins 5.2 and veins-vlc 1.0 versions.
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

it is written [here](https://veins.car2x.org/download/#compatibility) that for Windows it is necessary to install OMNeT++ 6.0 or use gcc instead of clang. Cite:

> Note that, on Windows, using Veins with other module libraries (such as the INET Framework, via veins_inet) is only supported for OMNeT++ 6.0pre14 (or OMNeT++ 5.6.2 when using the non-clang toolchain)